# Rotating a RelativeLayout in Android 2.3

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio

I am new to android and would like some assistance on rotating my relative layout for a two-player game I am working on.  I have seen the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103793/how-to-rotate-a-relativelayout-by-180-degrees?rq=1) and have looked into many other posts on the same subject on SO.  My first question is how to I call the new class I just made?  For all the posts that dont just tell me to use android:rotation (which is not avaliable in 2.3-) I make a new class, but I get a notification that the class is never called.  Do I call the class simmilar to how I call a method?  Or is there some command in AndroidManifest?  Finialy, how does the new class rotate only one Relative layout and not the other?  I just would like to know how its supposted to work.
This is the new Class that I am supposted to make:

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {    
public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {
    t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);
    Matrix m = t.getMatrix();
    m.reset();
    m.postRotate(180, child.getWidth() / 2.0f, child.getHeight() / 2.0f);
    return true;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What the post has done is called creating a "custom view". You still have to create or inflate it and have it added to the view heirarchy. Relevant place in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

In the oncreate() method in your activity  do `setContentView(new MyRelativeLayout(this))`

Comment: This is one way of doing it Ritaban, yes. Don't forget `()` token after `new MyRelativeLayout()`. However, in *many* cases the OP might want to add their custom view to the view heirarchy some other way. Perhaps we should wait until the OP has indicated more?

Comment: @Tom What should be put into the '()' after 'new MyRelativeLayout' ?

Comment: New MyRelativeLayout(this)