# Which is called first the constructor or onDraw()

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912406/view-ondraw-when-does-it-get-called) but it does not offer what I am asking about.

I have some variables which are declared globally and, initially, they are assigned to NULL. Inside the constructor I call a function called `"newGame()"`, this function initialise the variables. And inside `onDraw()` I am trying to draw a text contains the size of one of the variables that I have initialised inside the `newGame()` function, and when I run the app, it crashes, and `logCat` says: `NPE`.

So, i think, if the constructor is called first, my variables should have been initialsed, so that there should be no `NPE`. But, since there is `NPE`, it seems that, `onDraw()` is called before the constructor, is that true?

***Update_1***

I have also placed the `newGame()` function inside `onSizeChanged()` but, I receive the same `NPE`

***Update_2***

I am checking if an object of a `hashmap`is null or not like this in the following:
`if (obj == null)`  is it correct to check whether or not an object is null?

***Update_3***

here is how I initialise the "hand"

```
if (hand == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "@dealCards: Hand hashMap was NULL, it will be initialised");
        hand = new HashMap<Integer, Card>();
    }
```

***Code***

```
private HashMap<Integer, Card> deck = null;
private HashMap<Integer, Card> tableHand = null;
private HashMap<Integer, Card> myHand = null;
private HashMap<Integer, Card> compHand = null;
....
....
//CONSTRUCTOR
    public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = context;
    scale = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    textPaint = new Paint();
    textBounds = new Rect();
    deckSize_String = "Deck_Size: ";
    cardArraySize_String = "cardsArraySize: ";

    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    textPaint.setTextSize(scale*15);

    newGame();
}
....
....
//OnDraw()
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawText("tableHand: "+tableHand.size(), 10, 200, textPaint);

}

private void newGame() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "@newGame()");

    initDeck();
    dealCards(deck, tableHand);
    myTurn = whosTurn();

    if (myTurn) {
        dealCards(deck, myHand);
        dealCards(deck, compHand);
    }else {
        dealCards(deck, myHand);
        dealCards(deck, compHand);
    }
}
...
...
...
 private void dealCards(HashMap<Integer, Card> deck, HashMap<Integer, Card> hand) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (hand == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "@dealCards: Hand hashMap was NULL, it will be initialised");
        hand = new HashMap<Integer, Card>();
    }

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        hand.put( (hand.size()+1), deck.get( ((DECK_MAX_SIZE - deck.size())+1) ) );
        copyDealtCards( dealtCardsPile, deck.get( ((DECK_MAX_SIZE - deck.size())+1) ) );
        deck.remove( ((DECK_MAX_SIZE - deck.size())+1) );
    }
}
```

Comment: If the constructor wasn't invoked, what would `onDraw()` be invoked on?

Comment: Post the code so someone can take a look

Comment: The constructor has to be called on an object before any non-static functions are called on it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if there was no constructor, however, onDraw() will try to draw a text which has not been initialised. is it your question, did i got you right?

Comment: @kharyam i posted the code

Comment: `onDraw` is an instance method. You need an instance to invoke it on. To create an instance, you need to invoke a constructor. You don't seem to be initializing `tableHand` correctly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can i check if an object is null or not as the following: `if (obj == null)` or it is not correct

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis please take a look at updated_3 above

Comment: Yeah, but _where_ is that code?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis please see the updated Code. `dealCards` methods, in which i initialise the hands

Comment: Is `dealCards` called before `onDraw`? We keep going back and forth on this. If you get a NPE in `onDraw`, that's because something is `null`. Figure out what that is and initialize before `onDraw` is called.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `dealcards` is a function and is called from inside `newGame()` which is called from the constructor.in other words, the constructor has `newGame()` and `newGame` has dealCards()

Comment: I don't see `newGame` getting called.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry for any inconvenience caused. please see the code updated

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Saw your added code, where did you initialize tableHand?

By the way, it is better to declare tableHand as Map instead of HashMap, and initialize it with new HashMap<>().

---

No doubt, constructor. If the object does not exist first, no instance method can be invoked on it.

Comment: For non-static methods

Comment: You can invoke static methods without creating an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try and follow this design to be sure you are initiating the variables properly

```
class Foo {
    private static String GLOBAL_VAR = null ;
    private        String instanceVariable = null ;

    static {
        // here you can do complicated stuff 
        //in order to correctly initiate your variables.
        GLOBAL_VAR = "FOO" ; 
    }// this block will run when the class is loaded

    {
        // here you can do complicated stuff 
        //in order to correctly initiate your variables.
        instanceVariable = "foo" ;  
    }// this block will run before constructor.

    Foo()
    {

    }//Constructor

    static String getGlobalVar()
    {
         return GLOBAL_VAL ;
    }
}
```